# Getting the page url in OnPreRender Event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I just ran into a problem. Before I was getting the URL of the Page in Page_Init method. Now to load the css based on the page in the URL, I had to shift the method into the OnPreRender event.

> HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl

But when I do so I m not able to get the page url. All I get is "Page-Not-Found.aspx".
Is there a way to get the URL in OnPreRender Method?
Thanks

Comment: HAve you tried HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ASP.net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.80%29.aspx)
In the start step, page properties such as Request and Response are set. At this stage, the page also determines whether the request is a postback or a new request and sets the IsPostBack property. Additionally, during the start step, the page's UICulture property is set.

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        Response.Write(this.Context.Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

**It is working fine and Request object is created at my side..**